# WPF: How do I perform custom rendering of items in List or Grid?

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, rendering, itemrenderer

With Adobe Flex I would create a custom ItemRenderer to change the display of items in a grid. This executes some code that overrides how the grid control renders items. How do I do this with WPF? What are the performance implications with the techniques available?

My initial aim is to display an icon, a title, and a description. Ideally the description would be under the title. A similar UI is used by the Vista TaskDialog buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Data Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatemplate.aspx). You can set it for ItemTemplate (ListBox), CellTemplate (GridViewColumn), HeaderTemplate, etc.

Performance depends on how complex the template is, but for what you described, you should not notice a difference.